# Deployment strategy - Spring Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, deployment, enterprise

Need everyone's view/help in Deployment strategy of enterprise applications. The web layer components like jsps, servlets, spring controllers will be packaged as war file, and business logic, data access logic components will be packaged as jar file. Now if we want to deploy war file in web server & jar file in application server, how the communication should happen from web layer to business layer? Do we need to expose the business layer components as webservices?

Also, as the spring controllers(in war) will be having bean references to business layer components how the war file will be deployed in web server, while starting the application the bean references will be checked. If the bean references are not found, the application won't start. If we package the jar in web-inf/lib, it means we are deploying the jar file also in web server itself. Physically, the deployment of war & jar files wont be in the same jvm/server. Also, the business components are not ejbs to do a jndi lookup.

In this case, how the deployment strategy should be worked out? Please guide accordingly.

Comment: why do you need to separate web layer from business logic in two different servers?